# How do I make a model formset based on another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I currently have two Django Models, on it like a setup model and another is the actual data for that model. Like this:

```
class Extra(models.Model):
    has_text = models.BooleanField(u'Has Text', default=False)
    has_image = models.BooleanField(u'Has Image', default=False)
    has_file = models.BooleanField(u'Has File', default=False)


class OrderExtra(models.Model):
    extra = models.ForeignKey('Extra')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_order_extra_upload_path, blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_order_extra_upload_path, blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I've been trying to make a formset of the `OrderExtra` that is linked up to a queryset of the `Extra` that I've filtered out. Then hide the fields of the unchecked boxes of the `Extra`.

I though about making a form for the `Extra` and replacing the fields on creation, but I wasn't sure how to do this properly...

If anyone could help me, or provide some direction that would be fantastic, because I'm stuck on how to do this...

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make form for OrderExtra and in *init* of it add checked fields from related extra object

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    has_text = None

    class Meta():
        model=OrderExtra

    def __init__(self, *args , **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args , **kwargs)
        if self.instance and self.instance.extra.has_text:
            self.has_text = forms.BooleanField(...)
```

You can do this also for has_image and has_file

Comment: I`m not sure if it is exactly what you want

Comment: It's probably what author meant, but your code would result in exception being thrown if we deal with a new form that doesn't have declared relation to any Extra instance yet.

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying, this isn't quite what I was looking for, I was looking for the fields of the orderExtraForm to be shown based on the queryset of the Extra model, (ie. the OrderExtra text field will show up if the has_text is present in the Extra model.). I think I have a solution, that I will post if it works.